# Regarding StreamReader

Tags: c#

Why is this not working ?

```
StreamReader m = new StreamReader("../folder1/email.html", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

code file and html file are in diff folders so I that its some path issue but its not because I just now copied this html file in the same folder where this code file is and changed code to:

```
StreamReader m = new StreamReader("email.html", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

still not working.. What's wrong? Is the syntax wrong or what?

Comment: What's the error message that you are getting?

Comment: *Not working* is not a very precise problem description. Are you getting some exception?

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints to improve this question to the point where it can be answered.

Comment: no error msg..the code line next to this one doesnt work..it works when I comment out this code..I mean the code stops working when this code line is encountered

Comment: @Darin..ther's no error msg, no exception either

Comment: @Happy Soul: what result do you expect that you don't get?

Comment: @Fredrik..I need to read this html file using StreamReader then put it in a string using String myString=m.ReadToEnd(); Its not reading the file..I tried displaying myString..not working still..It just wont read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a relative path it will be relative to the bin/Debug or bin/Release folder, not the project folder where your code file is, so try:

```
m= new StreamReader("../../email.html", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: He would get an exception if the file location was wrong and according to his comments there's no exception.

Answer (score 1):

You say that there's no exception with your code. This means that the file is successfully opened for reading. I suspect that you are not reading anything from this `StreamReader`, you are simply instantiating it and probably not releasing.

Make sure you dispose this stream or you might leak handles. If all you need to do is read the file contents you could use the [ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx) method:

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText("email.html");
```

If the file is not found you will get an exception.

Comment: I did write m.Close(); after reading the file n using it..isn't that how u dispose? I need to use StreamReader only

Comment: You properly dispose with the [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not reading it ...try this ...put the file in your Bin/Debug directory and...

```
 StreamReader m = new StreamReader("email.html", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

 Console.Write(m.ReadToEnd()); 

 Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Isn't ReadToEnd() doing just that ? reading the file?? I tried ur code..still not working

Comment: Are you in Debug or Release mode. Dont put the email.html in the code file directory ... put it in the Bin/Debug and/or Bin/Release directory... the folders where the executable file resides.